# Finding the time complexity of the algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

I need to write an algorithm that find the length of loop in linked list and return (if the loop exists) and also return an element in the loop.
if there is no loop in the list,return None.
here is my code:

```
def find_circle(self):
    slower = self.head
    faster = self.head
    while (slower is not None and faster is not None):
        if faster.next is not None:
            faster = faster.next.next
        slower = slower.next
        if slower == faster:
            counter = 1
            slower = slower.next
            while slower != faster:
                slower = slower.next
                counter += 1
            return counter, slower.data
    return None
```

the code need to be in time complexity of O(n) and additional space complexity of O(1).
Is this code fits the time and space complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the time complexity of the above code is `O(n)` and the space complexity is `O(1)` as you are not storing the entire list.

```
def find_circle(self):
    // Space O(1)
    slower = self.head
    faster = self.head

    // Looping through only once, hence time complexity is O(n)
    while (slower is not None and faster is not None):
        if faster.next is not None:
            faster = faster.next.next
        slower = slower.next
        if slower == faster:
            counter = 1
            slower = slower.next
            while slower != faster:
                slower = slower.next
                counter += 1
            return counter, slower.data
    return None
```

Comment: It takes a more nuanced argument to explain why this runs in time O(n). For example, if the list does contain a cycle, how do you know that the two pointers will hit each other in O(n) steps and not, say, O(n^2) steps? There are n^2 possible pairs of positions in a cycle that the two pointers can take on, and you'd need to explain why you won't go through all of them before the two meet.